# Is it possible to make an AutoHotkey script activate on the PC without stopping mouse button actions?

Tags: autohotkey

There is this script that pulls the cursor down when the left mouse button is pressed.

The idea is that the script is activated when the right mouse button is pressed, but if you set it as shown here, then the right mouse button works exclusively to turn the script on and off. Neither in the system nor in games it is pressed.

Is there any way to make the script activated on the pcm, and at the same time the button does not stop working everywhere except the script?

Thank you in advance.

```
Hotkey, RButton, CheckBox
Gui, Add, Text, xm ym+33, Speed:
Gui, Add, Edit, xm+40 ym+30 vSpeed w240 ,1
Gui, Add, Text, xm ym+63 , Timer (ms):
Gui, Add, Edit, xm+40 ym+60 vTimer w240
Gui, Add, CheckBox, xm+200 ym+97 vED gCheckBox, Toggle Script
Gui, Add, Button, xm ym+90 w100 gButtonApplyChanges , Apply Changes
Gui, Show

Hotkey, LButton Up , LeftButtonUp , Off
Hotkey , LButton , LeftButton , Off
Return

GuiClose:
ExitApp

LeftButton:
    Gui , Submit , NoHide
    SendInput , {LButton Down}
    SetTimer , DragDown , % 10 / Speed
    SetTimer , StopDragDown , % Timer
Return

LeftButtonUp:
    SendInput , {LButton Up}
    SetTimer , DragDown , Off
Return

DragDown:
    Gui , Submit , NoHide
    DllCall("mouse_event" , "UInt" , 0x01 , "UInt" , 0 , "UInt" , 1 + Speed)
Return

StopDragDown:
    SetTimer , DragDown , Off
Return

CheckBox:
    Gui , Submit , NoHide
    If (A_ThisHotkey = "RButton")
        GuiControl,, ED,% !ED
    Gui , Submit , NoHide
    Stat := (ED) ? "On" : "Off"
    Hotkey,LButton,% Stat
    Hotkey,LButton Up,% Stat
Return

ButtonApplyChanges:
    Gui , Submit,NoHide
    If (HotkeyC != HotkeyCC) {
        Hotkey,% HotkeyCC := HotkeyC,% CheckBox,% On
        Hotkey,% HotkeyCC,% CheckBox,% Off
    }
Return
```

I don't understand how to solve the problem please help